# Subtle compensations

Tags: real-analysis, algebra-precalculus, functions, calculus-of-variations

I need to do this exercice **without using differentiation**.

$f$ is defined on $[1; +\infty[$ as $f(x)=\sqrt{x-4\sqrt{x-1}+3} + \sqrt{x-6\sqrt{x-1}+8}$

a. Show that $f$ is constant on $[5; 10]$.

b. Simplify the expression of $f(x)$ for $x\in [1; 5]$, and then for $x\in [10; +\infty]$.

Thanks!

Comment: Please provide some context as to what you have attempted in the process of solving this problem.

Comment: I tried to take the square of the function and see if it was constant (given that $f$ is positive, if its square is constant then the function itself is constant).

This did not help since we still have a square root that I cannot simplify.

Answer (score 1):

$\sqrt{x-4\sqrt{x-1}+3}=\sqrt{x-1-4\sqrt{x-1}+4}=\sqrt{\sqrt{x-1}^2-4\sqrt{x-1}+2^2}=|\sqrt{x-1}-2|$

$\sqrt{x-6\sqrt{x-1}+8}=\sqrt{x-1-6\sqrt{x-1}+9}=\sqrt{\sqrt{x-1}^2-6\sqrt{x-1}+3^2}=|\sqrt{x-1}-3|$

$f(x)=|\sqrt{x-1}-2|+|\sqrt{x-1}-3|$

From here you have to see what happens when $x \in [1,5]$, $x \in [5,10]$, and $x \in [10,\infty)$.

For example $\sqrt{x-1}-2\ge 0$ and $\sqrt{x-1}-3 \le 0$ if $x \in [5,10]$ then $f(x)=\sqrt{x-1}-2-(\sqrt{x-1}-3)=1$

Comment: Thanks a lot @kmitov, it is perfectly clear now!